# Python UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode, encoding

In Python 2.7, see the following error, when trying to cast type to ensure it matches the output schema.

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character in position
>   0: ordinal not in range(128)
>   Tried to find why and reproduced the error in Jupiter. By simply typing in.

```
str(u'\u2013')
```

What is the way to cast type to string that can handle this type of error? Thanks!

Comment: A side question, what  u'\u'` pattern of string means?

Comment: It defines a Unicode string, which the Python 2 `str` type cannot hold. This is much more manageable in Python 3; you should definitely not be using Python 2 to learn Python any longer!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I will answer my own question. Found an duplicated question. stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/

But for **simplicity**, here is an elegant solution that works well with my use case:

```
def safe_str(obj):
    try: return str(obj)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        return obj.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
    return ""

safe_str(u'\u2013')
```

Or simply use:

```
u'\u2013'.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Comment: `print(whatever.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))`

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```
u'\u2013'.encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 2):

For version 2.7.x ,encoding is not set by default.
Please use below code as a first line of program

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Your code goes below this line
```

It should solve your problem.

For python 3.x ,there is default encoding.hence there will be no issue of encoding.

Comment: No. This did not work.

Comment: This did not works in my python3 program.